# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'list' before initialization

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am now working on a project where I am using mongoose, and I am facing an issue that I checked that if there is already a document available with the same name in my database what I searched for, If its available then return a that page if not available then create a new document with that name. But the main issues that in console its showing that

```
          **ReferenceError: Cannot access 'list' before initialization **
```

I am given my code and console view can someone suggets in which point I have to change.

in my app.js file ...........

```
app.get('/:customListName', function(req,res){
       const customListName=req.params.customListName;

       List.findOne({name:customListName}).then(function(foundList){

         // if(!err){
           if(foundList===null){
             const list= new list({
               name:customListName,
               items:foundItem
             });

             list.save();
             res.render('/'+customListName);
               console.log(foundList);
           }else{
               res.render("list", {listTitle: customListName, newListItems: foundItem});

           }
         

       });


});
```

but in console ......

C:\Users\suraj\Documents\Web development-2\todolist-v2-starting-files\app.js:79
const list= new list({
^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'list' before initialization
at C:\Users\suraj\Documents\Web development-2\todolist-v2-starting-files\app.js:79:26
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.13.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

[image]

So can someone suggest some solution?

Comment: `const list=new list(...` is definitely going to cause a problem. Should it be `new List` instead of `new list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I was supposed to use `new List` instead of `new list`.

here is the code...............>

```
 app.get('/:customListName', function(req,res){
       const customListName=req.params.customListName;

       List.findOne({name:customListName}).then(function(foundList){

         // if(!err){
           if(foundList===null){
             const list= new List({
               name:customListName,
               items:foundItem
             });

             list.save();
             res.render('/'+customListName);
               console.log(foundList);
           }else{
               res.render("list", {listTitle: customListName, newListItems: foundItem});

           }
         

       });


});
```